# Routing link nested components

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem with the router link. Initially I have this situation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBdXZ.jpg

Clicking in a component 0's  button the situation changes in this way

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLYya.jpg

I created an app-routing service to manage the routing

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/a', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'a',  component: component 0 },
  { path: 'b', component: component 2 },
  { path: 'c', component: component 3 },
  { path: 'd', component:component 4}
  { path: 'e', component:component 5}


];
```

and I added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the component 1's template.
This works well.

Now clicking in a button of the component 3 I would this situation

[http://imgur.com/a/CcW4i](https://imgur.com/a/CcW4i)

Instead I have this

[http://imgur.com/a/mubas](https://imgur.com/a/mubas)

I tried different ways but without results, where is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share more of your code?  Also, your `redirectTo` should be the path you want to redirect to, not the component name.

Comment: I corrected the redirectTo in this post. Which code's part do you want? The code is so big, I have several component

Comment: You don't have to give entire components, but any parts related to routing would be helpful.  For instance, to be able to see are you using relative paths in your routerLinks and naviation, etc.

Comment: I manage the routing link only with the app-routing service that I wrote and [routerLink] (for example [routerLink]="['/c']") that I associated to the buttons, for this I didn't understand for the code that you asked.

Comment: I don't know if I have to add a second  <router-outlet></router-outlet> inside the nested component 4 and change the Routes

Comment: Maybe.  The routing config code I see is a flat routing structure.  What nested routing or what components do you want to be children of other components?  Then I can help you come up with a routing config that matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/a', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'a',  component: Component0 },
  { path: 'b', component: Component1,



      children: [
        { path: 'c',  component: Component2 },
        { path: 'd',  component: Component3},
        { path: 'e',  component: Component4,

          children: [
            { path: 'f',  component: Component5 },
            { path: 'g',  component: Component6 },
            { path: 'h',  component: Component7 }

          ]
        }
      ]
  }
];
```

P.S. In this "version" I added some extra components with respect to the initial post.